# MySQL data not getting displayed in a PHP webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get some data from MySQL to be displayed on a PHP webpage but no data is getting displayed.

I have the variables `searchterm` and `searchtype` declared higher up in the HTML code. The HTML code only has an option of a drop down menu and an option for the user to search.

When I run the code however, no data is displayed. All I get is: "Number of projects found:" which is where the data is meant to be displayed.

The full HTML and PHP code that I have is shown below.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <form action="list_projects.php" method="POST">
            <p>Choose Search Type: <br /></p>
            <select name="searchtype">
                <option value="projectNo">Project Number</option>
                <option value="pjname">Project Name</option>
                <option value="city">Project City</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <p>Enter Search Term: </p>
            <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="20"/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

        <?php
            $hostname='mysql.uniwebsite.ac.uk';
            $database='somedatabase';
            $username='uniusername';
            $password='unipassword';

            $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
            if (!$link) {
                die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

            $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
            $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
            if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
                echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
                exit;
            }

            $query = "select * FROM tables WHERE ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
            for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Project Number: ";
                echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['projectNo']));
                echo "</strong><br />Project Name: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['pjname']);
                echo "<br />Project City: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['city']);
                echo "</p>";
            }
            $mysqli_free_result($result);
            $mysqli_close($link);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following errors are what I get when I turn error reporting on:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/list_projects.php on line 39
Number of projects found:


Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_free_result in /home/list_projects.php on line 52

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/list_projects.php on line 52
```

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs, for one thing and is so far what's breaking your code. Whether you have values for your POST arrays, is unknown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't see the mix of MySQL APIs and it's been fixed in the code

Comment: Your original post says differently http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36536087/1 - `$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: So now the question is: where are those POST arrays being taken from? There's no way to know if your (unknown) HTML form has all the right parts. You're also not checking for errors anywhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- which is why I've edited it so that it's relevant to what I have on my local machine.

Comment: Wondering why noone's mentioning the safety state of your code. You're directly using `$_POST` values in your query, that makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, I don't see where you're selecting your db. (See [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.select-db.php))

Comment: You also didn't choose a database. Unless you'll be re-editing that also(?) Oh, not my dv, btw. and `mysqli_error()` requires a parameter for it.

Comment: Now you added your HTML form and using it inside the same file. You should be getting some undefined index notices, along with not choosing a database. I believe I have debugged 99.9% of your code ;-) Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: @ccKep it's a little project that I'm trying to work on myself and I've been allowed to use the university server to retrieve data that they've put on

Comment: @Fred-ii- how would I go about selecting a database?

Comment: @smitthy depening on the db permissions they gave you, anyone would be able to edit/delete/insert stuff into that database as of now.

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);` ;-) `die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I have `$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
   if (!$link) {
       die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error());
   }` but still no data is being shown :/

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`. Best I can offer as I said a few times already, but I guess you didn't go to PHP.net to look up the syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll edit the question with what I get.

Comment: @smitthy Could've atleast fixed those `$<function name>` errors before editing. Anyway: `$result` being a boolean hints `mysqli_query` returning `FALSE` for your select statement. Add error checking code and print the output. (`mysqli_error($link)`)

Comment: @ccKep I have `mysqli_error` in the code

Comment: But not for checking the result of `mysqli_query`... Do you want us to guide you through every single step? [The PHP.net mysqli_query doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) has examples on how to connect+query a database using the mysqli API. Take that as an example for error checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improved code to help you on your way, see the `Change:` and `Homework:` lines:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <form action="list_projects.php" method="POST">
            <p>Choose Search Type: <br /></p>
            <select name="searchtype">
                <option value="projectNo">Project Number</option>
                <option value="pjname">Project Name</option>
                <option value="city">Project City</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <p>Enter Search Term: </p>
            <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="20"/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

        <?php
            // Change 1: Enable error reporting
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);

            $hostname='mysql.uniwebsite.ac.uk';
            $database='somedatabase';
            $username='uniusername';
            $password='unipassword';

            // Change 2: Add $database
            $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

            // Change 3: Literally copy&paste error checking from mysqli_query docs page
            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            // Homework: Check for legal values in more detail
            $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
            $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
            if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
                echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
                exit;
            }

            // Homework: Use prepared statements to avoid sql injection
            $query = "select * FROM tables WHERE ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";

            // Change 4: Error checking
            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
            {
                $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
                for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Project Number: ";
                    echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['projectNo']));
                    echo "</strong><br />Project Name: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['pjname']);
                    echo "<br />Project City: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['city']);
                    echo "</p>";
                }

                // Change 5.1: Remove $
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else {
                printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
            }

            // Change 5.2: Remove $
            mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```